# how to create a table between 2 rows of an other table?

Tags: html

i'm in a situation where i need to display a table (to hold data retrieved from a database) between rows if a certain condition is fulfilled.

so to simplify the problem, let us imagine i have a table with only 2 TRs, and 2 TD per TR:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
         <td>First row</td> <td>First row</td>
    </tr>
     <!-- how to insert a table here ?-->
     <tr>
          <td>Second row</td> <td>Second row</td>
     </tr>    
 </table>
```

How to insert a table between the 2 rows using html? the inserted table must have the same number of columns (2 TD as the available one  but I do not care for rows))

Comment: add a row with two colspan and write your table code there..

Comment: ok but why 2 colspan for the new tr?

Comment: yes after a TR as shown in my example @Milan

Comment: so that it will occupy two td's width

Comment: @ABUdhay you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another row with a data cell that spans for two column and can then put your nested table inside the cell.

```
   <table >
      <tr>
        <td>First row</td>
        <td>First row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <table >
          <tr>
            <td>First row in nested table</td>
            <td>First row in nested table</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Second row</td>
        <td>Second row</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7oveyv4r/1/

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot directly place a table inside a table. As a work around we can do like this,

```
<tr colspan="2">
<td>
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>Inner Cell11</td> <td>Inner Cell12</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>Inner Cell21</td> <td>Inner Cell22</td>
     </tr>    
 </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: if you use without colspan then your first td will be empty. hence suggested for colspan.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>First row</td> <td>First row</td>
</tr>
<!-- new code below-->
<tr >
<td colspan=2> <!-- keep colspan has many as columns in parent table-->
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Inner rows</td><td>Inner rows</td>
    </tr>    
    </table> 
</td>   
</tr>
<!-- new code ends-->    
<tr>
<td>Second row</td> <td>Second row</td>
</tr>    
</table>
```